# Wordpress - Error with Divi widget builder

Tags: wordpress, divi

I encountered a problem while trying to activate the Divi Widget Builder plugin. When I attempt to activate the plugin, I receive the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function create_function() in /home/helloge/www/wp-content/plugins/divi-widget-builder/divi-widget-builder.php:137 Stack trace: #0 /home/helloge/www/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php(2314): include_once() #1 /home/helloge/www/wp-admin/plugins.php(192): plugin_sandbox_scrape('divi-widget-bui...') #2 {main} thrown in /home/helloge/www/wp-content/plugins/divi-widget-builder/divi-widget-builder.php on line 137
```

I want to clarify that the system, plugins, and PHP are all up to date with the latest versions.

I tried to uninstall and reinstall both Divi Widget Builder and Divi. If you can provide a solution, it would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like the plugin author needs to update their code as that function was removed in PHP 8 - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php